# Data frame Date-Time Row Filtration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with several columns and rows, I have a column of 'Date' ( month/day/ year Hour:Min: Sec PM' and I need to get from the data frame only the rows that that match the Hour:Min:Sec part of that column. The column has the data as object.

```
    df.loc[df['Date']== 'month/day/year 11:00:00 PM'].copy
```

It only works when I specify the month/day/year, but I want to obtain the rows that correspond to the time no matter the day. Does any one know how can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in 2 steps. The first creates an intermediate col with the time only. The second does the filtering.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df =pd.DataFrame([[datetime(2018,1,1,2,2,2),1], [ datetime(2018,1,1,3,3,3),2]], columns=['Date','Val'])
                 Date  Val
0 2018-01-01 02:02:02    1
1 2018-01-01 03:03:03    2
```

1) Create intermediate col

```
>>> df['new'] = df['Date'].transform(lambda x: x.time())
>>> df
                 Date  Val       new
0 2018-01-01 02:02:02    1  02:02:02
1 2018-01-01 03:03:03    2  03:03:03
```

2) Do filtering

```
>>> df[df['new'] == datetime.time(2,2,2)]
                 Date  Val       new
0 2018-01-01 02:02:02    1  02:02:02
```